# extjs message box show

Tags: javascript, extjs, messagebox

I am using the Extjs Messagebox in my application. When the Message box appears on screen, it appears at below other window. How can i show message box on top of other windows. i'm using extjs ver: 3.4.0

this is my screen shot: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(function () { yourGridWindow.toBack();}).defer(100);
```